# Error converting 32-bit integer input to IP address

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a 32-bit integer input to an IP address, but I'm having difficulty get the IP address printed correctly.

For example, I'm providing my program a 32-bit integer of `10000000111111110000001100001111` and the result I'm getting is `.......128........33023........8453891........2164196111`.

```
def main():
    integer_input = input('Welcome. Please provide a 32 bit integer.')
    ip = ''
    value = 0

    for i, d in enumerate(integer_input):
        value *= 2
        value += int(d)

        if (i+1) % 8 == 0:
            ip += str(value)
        if (i+1) is not 32:
            ip += '.'

    value = 0
    print(ip)

main()
```

Comment: What's the desired output???

Comment: `divmod` should help you split the 32-bit int into four 8-bit ints, then you just need `str()` and `join()`.

Comment: IP address e.g. 128.164.122.21

Comment: @floater This is not so clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` is reused for all octets and is never reset back to `0` after printing out the value.  If you reset `value` back to 0 after the octet is calculated, you will get the correct result.

Basically add `value = 0` to the following block, i.e.:

```
        if (i+1) % 8 == 0:
            ip += str(value)
            value = 0
```

Execution:

```
>>> main()
Welcome. Please provide a 32 bit integer.10000000111111110000001100001111
.......128........255........3........15
```

Also, you never want to use `is` to compare equality between numbers.  I.e. you should have this instead

```
        if (i+1) != 32:
```